# I find it difficult to link my javascript to my html

Tags: javascript, html

> Hi everyone!
> Please, I tried linking up my javascript to my html file using a sublime text editor. I am actually working on a e-commerce website using the frameworks if html, css, and javascript.

Help me guys.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as linking to it. If that doesn't work, then your link to the javascript is incorrect.
`<script src="myscripts.js"></script>`

If you have more info on your file structure (where the html you're writing and js you're linking to are located) it might be easier to help. For example if you're working in index.html in the diagram below, the link would be `<script src="js/myscripts.js"></script>`

```
yoursite/
├── css/
│   └── styles.css
├── js/
│   └── myscripts.js
└─ index.html
```